# Have problems building neo4j GetAll server extension

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.py

I have been trying to build the example GetAll neo4j server extension, but unfortunately I cannot make it work. I installed the Windows version of neo4j and run it as a server. I also installed Python neo4jrestclient and I am accessing neo4j through Python scripts. The following works fine:
    from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
    gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
    print gdb.extensions

It gives me "CypherPlugin" and "GremlinPlugin". I want to build the example GetAll server extension, which is Java. I am using Eclipse. I am able to create the jar file in the folder "c:\neo4j_installation_root\neo4j-community-1.7\plugins\GetAll.jar", but when I restart the neo4j server and run the neo4jrestclient it does not show the GetAll server extension. I searched a lot, but in vain. I have lots of experience with C++ and Python, but new to Java. I will really appreciate some help to be able to build neo4j server extensions. It is critically important for my evaluation of neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is a META-INF/services etc listing the plugin class, and the jar file is created with intermediate dirs (which is not the default in Eclipse export settings) so dirs are seen by the classloader?

Check out the tips at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-plugins.html

Comment: In the jar file "c:\KB\neo4j\neo4j-community-1.7\plugins\GetAll.jar" I have the following:

Comment: In "c:\KB\neo4j\neo4j-community-1.7\plugins\GetAll.jar" I have the following:
folder: META-INF\services\org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin
 The content of the file 'org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin' is:
org\neo4j\examples\server\plugins\GetAll

folder: org\neo4j\examples\server\plugins\GetAll.class

Still, when I launch "c:\KB\neo4j\neo4j-community-1.7\bin\Neo4j.bat" and run "curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/" it shows the extensions "CypherPlugin" and "GremlinPlugin", but does not show "GetAll" plugin.Had to change GraphDatabaseService to GlobalGraphOperations for getAllNodes().

Comment: are you producing the .jar with something like `jar -cvf myext.jar *` ? I am sure that is a JAR problem. Care to send over the file you are producing? peter at neotech.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do get-all with Bulbs (http://bulbflow.com) without building an extension:

```py
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.vertices.get_all()
>>> g.edges.get_all()
```

Custom models work the same way:

```py
# people.py

from bulbs.model import Node, Relationship
from bulbs.property import String, Integer, DateTime
from bulbs.utils import current_datetime

class Person(Node):

    element_type = "person"

    name = String(nullable=False)
    age = Integer()


class Knows(Relationship):

    label = "knows"

    created = DateTime(default=current_datetime, nullable=False)
```

And then call get_all on the model proxies:

```py
>>> from people import Person, Knows
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph

>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.add_proxy("people", Person)
>>> g.add_proxy("knows", Knows)

>>> james = g.people.create(name="James")
>>> julie = g.people.create(name="Julie")
>>> g.knows.create(james, julie)

>>> g.people.get_all()
>>> g.knows.get_all()
```